# org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryCompilerSyntaxException: Identifier expected at character 12 in "u.username== value"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, persistence, google-cloud-datastore

```
org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryCompilerSyntaxException: Identifier expected at character 12 in "u.username== value"
```

here is the query I'm trying to Execute :

```
try{
        Query q=em.createQuery("select u from UserJ u where u."+key+"== value");
        q.setParameter("value",value );
        return q.getResultList().isEmpty();
    }
    catch(PersistenceException x)
    {
        System.out.println(x.getLocalizedMessage());}
    finally{    
        em.close();
    }
```

Where is `key` is passed by value :`"username"`

and `value` is passed by value    :`"test"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, try this query instead:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select u from UserJ u where u."+key+" = :value");
```

Comment: That is great thanks but I have an extra exception :NullPointerException and it's caught when q.getResultList().isEmpty()  is true  (there is actually test value on database) why this happens and I'll be very thankful to You

Comment: What the value of `q.getResultList()` when you run it?

Comment: @YouYou - that means your query didn't return any values. Try running it in a SQL client to determine if it works as you intend.